# Field of sets versus a field as an algebraic structure

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, definition

During my studies of real analysis I've come across the definition of a field (or algebra) of sets.

My question is: What is the connection between this structure and the structure of a field or algebra known from abstract algebra?

Comment: The two use the same word.

Answer (score 7):

The term "field" in "field / algebra of sets over A" has no relation to the term "field" as used in ring theory. Rather it denotes a Boolean subalgebra of the power set of A, i.e. a collection of subsets of A closed under union, intersection and complement. The term is well-known due to its frequent use in the famous Stone representation theorem: $\ $every Boolean algebra is isomorphic to a field of sets. For further information see [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) and [this sci.math thread](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.logic/browse_frm/thread/20373f3ea47d79c0/cceccb1e3469a031).

Note: Boolean algebras can be considered as [Boolean rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring), i.e. rings where every element is idempotent, i.e. $\: x^2 = x\:$. However, except for the field of two elements, such rings are never fields: $\ 0 = x^2 - x = x\ (x-1)\ \Rightarrow\ x = 0\ \ {\rm or}\ \ x = 1\ $ in a field, i.e. fields have only trivial idempotents.