# What is so algebraic about the following definitions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a nonempty set. We say $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is an ***algebra*** if it is closed under finite union and complement. We say the same $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-***algebra*** if it is closed under countable union.

We say $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is an ***ring*** if it is closed under finite union and set difference. We say the same $\mathcal{R}$ is a $\sigma$-***ring*** if it is closed under countable union.

---

I am wondering if there is any connection between these terminologies and correspondent ones in abstract algebra. I think I have read somewhere that it is related to Boolean ring (I may be completely wrong), but I am afraid to sit down and write down details without if I am heading to a right direction. Any insightful comments or links (not for experts) will be appreciated.

Comment: See also [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/9574/23500)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal R$ be a collection of sets which is closed under symmetric differences and  intersections. Note that $\emptyset \in \mathcal R$. Then $\mathcal R$ is a commutative ring (in the algebraic sense) with addition defined by symmetric difference and multiplication defined by intersection, the zero of $\mathcal R$ is $\emptyset$. If we take the union of all the elements of $\mathcal R$ to be in $\mathcal R$ then it has a multiplicative identity. Note that for any $A \in \mathcal R$ we have $A+A=A \oplus A=\emptyset$ and $ A \cdot A=A \cap A=A$. It's a straightforward exercise to verify that the operations play nice and distribute as we would like. This sort of ring has a special name, it's what's called a [boolean ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring). In fact all such boolean rings arise in this manner by the [stone representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras).

So there is some correspondence between the notations, don't ask me why some people call them fields. The $\sigma$ that gets thrown in front is a general way to refer to some sort of countable condition. If you continuing studying measure theory you'll run into the concept of a [$\sigma$-finite measure space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure) and in topology a [$\sigma$-compact space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-compact_space).